# how to get selenium data on excel or csv?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Here is my full code. I want to get output data on csv such as title, price everything will be separated column on csv or excel spreadsheet. My code going to details page of each product and collecting my necessary information such as product title, price etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#argument for incognito Chrome
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--incognito")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

browser.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/consumer-electronics/?spm=a2a0e.pdp.breadcrumb.1.4d20110bzkC0bn")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c16H9d']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()

//getting link of each product 
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

product_items = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-qa-locator": "product-item"})
for item in product_items:
    item_url = f"https:{item.find('a')['href']}"
    print(item_url)

    browser.get(item_url)

    //scrape details page information 
    itm_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    container_box = itm_soup.find_all("div",{"id":"container"})
    # Use the itm_soup to find details about the item from its url.
    for itm in container_box:
        product_title_element = itm.find("span",class_="pdp-mod-product-badge-title")
        product_title = product_title_element.get_text() if product_title_element else "No title"
        print(product_title)

browser.quit()
```

how I will get product title on csv or excel spreadsheet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the csv writer module to accomplish this.

```
from csv import writer
def AddToCSV(List):
    with open("Output.csv", "a+", newline='') as output_file:
        csv_writer = writer(output_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(List)

# this can be used within your for loop
row_list = [item_url, product_title, price, etc..]
AddToCSV(row_list)
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen it worked. can please tell me how to give column name such as for item_URL I want give column name item_url, product_tile column name will be  product_tiltle.

Comment: You can use the same function before the loop begins to add the column names. Just pass on a list like `AddToCSV(['item_url', 'title', etc... ])`. But you should note that this will add a row everytime this script runs. So when running a second time, it will add column names again. If you have the same output file, that new column names might be in the middle of the file..